# FOR /F not assigning the last value

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Today is 11/01/2013

I have the following .bat file:

```
@ECHO OFF
:: Take the output from DATE and assign it to variable today
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=/" %%i IN ('DATE /T') do SET /A today=%%i

ECHO %today%
PAUSE
```

and it outputs:
11

If I am telling the FOR to iterate over the 3 tokens and then output the resulting variable: shouldn't it throw me the '2013' value, since it is the last token assigned to %%i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be getting three tokens.  Try this which will extract the third token only.

```
FOR /F "tokens=3 delims=/" %%i IN ('DATE /T') do SET /A today=%%i
```

See [for /f reference](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) for how this works.  The loop works on a line at a time and splits it up by the specified delimiter.

> FOR /F processing of a text file consists of reading the file, one line of text at a time and then breaking the line up into individual items of data called 'tokens'.

In this case you're executing a command, but that is treated like reading a file:

> A string of text will be treated just like a single line of input from a file, the string must be enclosed in double quotes (or single quotes with usebackq).

The `DATE /T' command is a single line that is split into three elements.

Comment: Ok, got it. However, isn't it the purpose of the '*' token to indicate that you want to iterate over all of the result set elements, one at a time? when I get to the last token, I would expect the iteration variable to have the last set value.

Comment: @madprofessor I've updated to explain how it works with a link to some good docs.  Hope it helps :)